# Hexadecimal Variable

Tags: linux, bash, script, linux-mint, hexadecimal

Okay so i tried to make a loop which increases an variable from 0 to FF (0x00 to 0xFF would also work):

```
...
declare -i register=0

while [ 255 -ge $register ]
do
  sudo mono ec-probe.exe read 0x+$register
  register=$register+1
done
...
```

This works but how can i make the loop run from 0 to FF?
Is there a possibilty for an hexadecimal variable?

Sincerly
Stefan

Answer (score 1, accepted):

bash will store the variable as a decimal integer, but you can do comparisons with a hex constant. You'll have to explicitly convert if you want to format the number as hex:

```
for ((register = 0; register <= 0xff; register++)); do
    printf -v hex %x $register
    echo "$register   $hex"
done
```

outputs

```
0   0
1   1
2   2
...
253   fd
254   fe
255   ff
```

Answer (score 0):

You've successfully created a loop that presents values from 0 to 255... now you need to format the decimal values as hexadecimal.

`printf` will do this no problem:

```
$ printf '0x%02X\n' 128
0x80
```

Pair that with your existing command like this:

```bsh
mono ec-probe.exe read $(printf '0x%02X' ${register})
```